# How to retrieve a column from database using SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, utility

I’m using database utility and in this example I’m inserting  some records

```
DBUtil.ExecuteNonQuery(@"if not exists(select * from UserTemplate)
   begin
     insert into UserTemplate
     select id, 8,1,….{TemplateCode} ….
     from User
  end”);
```

how can I extend this query to select `UsersImage` column from `UserTemplate` table?

P.S.  `UsersImage` is of `varbinary(MAX)` datatype.

Comment: That does not return a result set. You will need to rewrite the SQL statement and use a different method of `DBUtil`.

Comment: maybe I left something in a hurry, but question is how to extend the query to select UsersImage from UserTemplate table knowing that UsersImage is varbinary(MAX)?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `DBUtil` is, or if you want one specific image or all of them, I would guess you want something like this. Execute a reader that gets all images, read the varbinary field into a byte array, do something with the byte array.

```
using(SqlDataReader rdr = DBUtil.ExecuteReader("SELECT [UsersImage] FROM [UserTemplate]"))
{
    while(rdr.Read())
    {
        btye[] img = (byte[])rdr[0];
        //do something with img
    }
}
```